# No inputs were found in config file '....tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["**/*"]' and 'exclude'

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have this error but I don't know how to fix it, I do have a .ts file in src... here is my dockerfile for the backend and my tsconfig.json file.Thanks for your help.

```
FROM node:latest As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json  ./

COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN yarn install

RUN mkdir dist
RUN chown node:node dist


CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq5Qv.png)

I tried putting the src/* path in include, I tried putting a .ts file in the root but nothing works...